# NTFS permission for sub-folders

Tags: ntfs

I have a folder with many sub-folders.

Some of the sub-folders have inherited permission and others have additional NTFS permissions including "modify access".

How can I change the "modify access" only to "read-only access" using a script?

Answer (score 0):

#### How can I change the modify access to read only using a script?

You can use `icacls` to do this.Traverse all subfolders to match files/directories.

For example to change to "read-only" access for Everyone:

```
icacls "x:\somefolder\*" /t  /grant Everyone:R
```

Notes:

- `/t` - traverse all sub-folders to match files/directories
- Everyone - group "Everyone"

  The "Everyone" group contains "Users", "Authenticated users" and "Guests".
- `:R` - read-only access

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [icacls](http://ss64.com/nt/icacls.html) - Change file and folder permissions - display or modify Access Control Lists (ACLs) for files and folders.